# Python parse javascript for variable name and it's value

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse a javascript tag that has a variable named `options`. The value of options is an array,

```
"options: [[], []]"
```

How can I return the options list?

Currently I'm using BeautifulSoup but having trouble finding the text and also how the search would then convert the data after options into a python list

There is other text surrounding this variable and it's value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
json.loads(re.search("options: (.*)","adsasd\noptions: [[],[]]\nqqt").group(1))
```

is one way I guess... not a very good way i dont think ... I think we are missing alot of details in order to actually provide a useful answer

althoug I suspect your data looks more like this

```
"""
{
   key1:'value1',
   options: [[],[]],
   other:'somve other value'
}
"""
```

in which case you can just do

```
data = yaml.load(my_input_text)
print data['options']
```

(see below)

```
>>> data = yaml.load("""{   key1: 'value1',   options: [[],[]],   other: 'somve other value'}""")
>>> data
{'key1': 'value1', 'other': 'somve other value', 'options': [[], []]}
>>> data['options']
[[], []]
>>>
```